# libgdx get origin point and end point of actor (get two points on actor)

Tags: rotation, libgdx, drag, actor, point

I have an actor in libgdx, and want to move the actor along the finger dragging on the screen.
To follow the dragging finger,I am interested to match the center line of the actor to dragged line.

at least two points of actor I have to find .
How can I get two points on actor.

one is already origin(0,0) point. but i have to find the next.

Please give me the hint. or any other way of implementing it.
Thanks.

Comment: This is already the 4th or 5th kind of this question you ask in two days. I answered all of them so far. You should either get more precise on what exactly your problem is, or try a little bit yourself first and read some documentation. -> http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html

There is everything you want to know. Actor.getX(), Actor.getY(), Actor.getWidth(), Actor.getHeight()... that should be enough to calculate any point of the actor.

Comment: @noone , I am asking same kind of question because i am trying to solve the problem in different ways.
Thanks for your reply on the question.